# Issue with inherited style in Android

Tags: android, inheritance, coding-style

I'm using a custom dialog style to remove the white border. To achieve this, I created a custom style inheriting from Theme.Dialog, and set it in the dialog constructor. When not setting any style (I guess it takes Theme.Dialog as default), the dialog is centered both horizontally and vertically, but when I use my style, which just override android:windowBackground, my dialog is not centered anymore, so it seems that the style is not inherited...

Anybody can help?

Thanks!

My style:

```
<resources>
<style
    name="Theme_Dialog_Translucent"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>        
</style>
</resources>
```

My class:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
    Button okButton;

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {      
        //super(context); //if I use that the dialog is centered
        super(context, R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);      
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/confirmation"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:layout_width="279dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"   
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:text="@string/dialog_title"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_text"
        android:text="@string/dialog_text"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/confirmation"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_ok"
            android:background="@drawable/button_ok"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:text="ok"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"        
    />
    <Button android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_cancel"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I also have had this pain in the neck. am thus interested in the answer.